# How to jump between warnings in vim?

Tags: vim

How do you jump between warnings in vim?

In normal mode `:cn` command jumps only between errors, but I want to jump beetween warnings.

Comment: If you refer to the `type` attribute in `getqflist()`, for me `:cnext` also jumps to those that have the `W` value.

Answer (score 1):

What do you call "warning" and what plugin do you use to show warnings? If you are using Syntastic, "warnings" are probably "locations" from the "location list". You go to the next location with `:lnext` and to the previous one with `:lprevious`.